# Intel Sandy Bridge no sound through HDMI

Tags: 11.04, sound, hdmi

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 and I have an ASRock H67M-ITX/HT motherboard which is the Intel Sandy Bridge architecture.

I can't get sound to play through my TV on the HDMI interface. I have plugged in headphones and they work. I have also tried changing the device in sound preferences to the HDMI options provided

- Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output
- Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input
- Digital Stereo Duplex (IEC958)
- Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input

When I run the following command it plays sound fine.

```
aplay -D plughw:0,7 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

Comment: For the specific sound problem the answer here might help you with the HDMI sound: http://askubuntu.com/questions/54999/enable-hdmi-audio-on-nvidia-gtx470/104172#104172 Same procedure for having the sound through HDMI

Comment: Do you still experience this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I remember logging in and logging out after plugging in the HDMI device and changing the sound settings to HDMI Output seemed to help in my case.

Additionally, running 'alsamixer' in terminal seemed to have made a difference before.

Comment: I've given that a try but it still doesn't work. When I run alsamixer I can set all of the volume controls to 100% except the S/PDIF ones. I can't move them from 0%. I thought S/PDIF was optical audio so i'm not sure if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have a similar problem.  Audio plays fine in flash (e.g. youtube) and in VLC when I specifically select ALSA audio output and select the correct device (hw:0,7 for me too), it appears that by default the system isn't using these settings.

I'll keep looking for a way of forcing the system to use these setting, but in the mean time hope you find the above vlc tip useful?

Comment: I ended up using windows...

Comment: @Alex can't say a blame you I'm getting rather bored of this too.

Comment: Lol, It worked first time and i've never had a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I see that you tried selecting the correct options in the "Hardware" tab of Volume Preferences, but a couple times I've seen systems where you need to also choose the correct hardware in the "Output" tab.  Could this help?

Answer (score 1):

Open the *Terminal* and run *alsamixer* by typing `alsamixer` and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Use the arrow keys to go across to *S/PDIF 1* and press <kbd>M</kbd> to unmute it. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by opening "Sound Preferences" > "Hardware" then selecting "Digital Stereo (HDMI)" under "Settings for the selected device".